# LWC value comparison not working

Tags: lwc-wire-adapter, wire, lightning-web-components

I want to compare old and new values in LWC.

I want to show alert message when Account Rating field value changes to hot.

```
if (modifiedDate != this.lastModifiedDate || modifiedDate == this.lastModifiedDate ) {
    console.log('Console modified date---->',this.lastModifiedDate,modifiedDate);
    let rate = getFieldValue(this.account, RATING_FIELD) ?getFieldValue(this.account, RATING_FIELD) : ''
    let usrfield = getFieldValue(this.account, USER_FIELD) ?getFieldValue(this.account, USER_FIELD) : ''           
    console.log('Need user available field from user here>>'+ usrfield);

    const alertHotKey = `${this.recordId}_hot`;
    const alertHotAlreadyShown = sessionStorage.getItem(alertHotKey);

    if(!alertHotAlreadyShown && rate == 'Hot'){
        console.log('rate debug---->',rate);
        sessionStorage.setItem(alertHotKey, 'true');
        alert('YOU HAVE SELECTED ACCOUNT RATING AS HOT');
    }

    this.showNotification();
}
```

Comment: When is this alert shown? Which action triggers it? Does the user update a record using this component then the check on Account Ratings happens?

Comment: when field value of Account Rating field is changed to or selected as Hot. It shows alert message. my concern is to console the old value that is changed to  hot

Comment: If the update on Account record happens in this LWC, could you please share that code too?

Comment: if ( modifiedDate != this.lastModifiedDate ) {
                         
                const alertHotKey = `${this.recordId}`;                
                const alertHotAlreadyShown = sessionStorage.getItem(alertHotKey);               
                if(!alertHotAlreadyShown && rate == 'Hot')
                {                    
                    sessionStorage.setItem(alertHotKey, 'true');
                    alert('YOU HAVE SELECTED ACCOUNT RATING IS HOT');
                    this.showNotification();
                }

Comment: this  code in Question is for update.

Comment: I mean the code that execute the update on the record, in the one you posted there is the alert logic. How do you update the account? Calling `updateRecord` from `uiRecordApi` or calling an apex method?

Comment: import { LightningElement, api, wire,track } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

Comment: by getting getfieldvalue from uiRecordApi i am implementing my logic

Comment: You need to run something like this: `Select Id,Field, NewValue, OldValue,AccountId from AccountFieldHistory where AccountId = '0010k00000Asl4HAAR' and Field='Rating' `